# VBA Code stops working after saving and re-opening

Tags: vba

I hope that you can help.

I have added a VBA code which names Excel tabs in accordance to a cell within a worksheet but when I save the workbook and then reopen the VBA code has disappeared and no longer works.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Target = Range("D9")
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ActiveSheet.Name = VBA.Left(Target, 31)
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I need several Excel tabs to rename per whatever I type into a field, and after formatting each tab everything works and is all perfect until saving and reopening.

Please help,

Answer (score 0):

> when I save the workbook and then reopen the VBA code has disappeared

probably you've the workbook saved in a format which doesn't support macros (.xlsx), try to save it as .xlsm or .xlsb

See more [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-0943ff2c-6014-4e8d-aaea-b83d51d46247)